# Kaminari Navigation Menu doesn't show up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, kaminari

I'm using Kaminari for pagination.
Using the following lines in my controller:

```
@public_items =Array.new
@items= Item.all
@items.each do |item|
    if (item.is_public)
        @public_items <<item
    end
end
@public_items = Kaminari.paginate_array(@public_items).page(params[:page]).per(4)
```

and this line in my view

```
<%paginate @public_items %>
<% @public_items.each do |item| %>
.....
<%end%>
```

The pagination works fine meaning i can navigate to different pages by going to items?page=2 for example but the page navigation menu () doesn't show up!
and <%paginate @public_items %> does not create any html code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't it be:

```
<%= paginate @public_items %>
```

Including the equals sign. Without the equals sign it hides it.